# What's the different between write more and do more writing

Tags: grammar

"Jakes stopped acting to do more writing". I saw this sentence and wondered that if I can write " Jakes stopped acting to write more". Do they have the same meaning? or my sentence is more informal ? Thank for your help..

Answer (score 4):

I think that in this context your meaning is equally clear in either case, because it can be inferred that giving up acting gave Jakes more time to write.

However, in the absence of that context I would have said that "to do more writing" conveys your meaning more explicitly; whereas "to write more" might mean either to allocate more time to the activity of writing, or simply to add to a piece of writing that one is currently engaged in.

Regardless, I wouldn't say that one expression is more formal than the other.

Answer (score 0):

In general, one would say to give up x to do y.

- He gave up writing to **do more piano playing**.

writing and piano playing are activities, nouns.

That said to **write more** and to **do more writing**, as **to play piano more** or **do more piano playing** are basically the same thing.

- **To write more** expresses it as a verb.
- To **do more writing** expresses it as an activity.

Both are grammatical and do not differ in terms of formality.

Answer (score -1):

Both variants are equal in formality; that is, they share some, given tone. 
What does differ is style: to this, ask yourself, "How should the sentence feel? What best conveys the intent of the sentence?"

In this light, sentence no. 1 is heavier, more cumbersome.

Sentence no. 2 (your personal variation) flows more easily, phonetically and grammatically, offering thereby greater ease of apprehension for the reader.

I posit that your variant be favorable over the original text.